# How do I add json array element to the beginning of another json array?

Tags: arrays, json, jqgrid

So, I have json array:

`var preferencecolModel={name:'all',index:'all', width:40,     align:"left",resizable:false,sortable:false,editable:true};`

I need to add this to the beginning of another json array.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$.merge(preferencecolModel,(data[0].PREFERENCESMODEL));
preferenceColModel = $.parseJSON(preferencecolModel);
```

I'm quiet obviously wrong.
`data[0].PREFERENCESMODEL` comes from the database and looks something like this:

`[{"name":"HTML_DEVICE_CNT","index":"HTML_DEVICE_CNT","width":35,"align":"center","editable":true,"sortable":false,"resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":35},
{"name":"edit","index":"edit","width":20,"align":"center","editable":true,"sortable":false,"resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":20},
{"name":"SPONSOR_CLASSIFICATION","index":"SPONSOR_CLASSIFICATION","width":35,"align":"center","editable":true,"sortable":false,"resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":35},
{"name":"ENT_EXCEPTION_QUEUE","index":"ENT_EXCEPTION_QUEUE","width":60,"align":"center","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":60,"sortable":true},
{"name":"QIB","index":"QIB","width":30,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":30,"sortable":true},
{"name":"LAST_NAME","index":"LAST_NAME","width":120,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":120,"sortable":true},
{"name":"FIRST_NAME","index":"FIRST_NAME","width":120,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":120,"sortable":true},
{"name":"INSTITUTION_TYPE","index":"INSTITUTION_TYPE","width":120,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":120,"sortable":true},
{"name":"INSTITUTION_NAME","index":"INSTITUTION_NAME","width":190,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":190,"sortable":true},
{"name":"EXEMPTION","index":"EXEMPTION","width":70,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":70,"sortable":true},
{"name":"GRAND_PARENT","index":"GRAND_PARENT","width":80,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":80,"sortable":true},
{"name":"GFCID","index":"GFCID","width":80,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":80,"sortable":true},
{"name":"CONTACTID","index":"CONTACTID","width":80,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":80,"sortable":true},
{"name":"CREATED_DATE","index":"CREATED_DATE","width":90,"align":"left","resizable":false,"formatter":"date","formatoptions":{"srcformat":"Y-m-d","newformat":"m-d-Y"},"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":90,"sortable":true},
{"name":"TIERS","index":"TIERS","width":200,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":200,"sortable":true},
{"name":"EMAIL_ADDRESS","index":"EMAIL_ADDRESS","width":120,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":false,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":120,"sortable":true},
{"name":"ALTERNATE_EMAIL_ADDRESS","index":"ALTERNATE_EMAIL_ADDRESS","width":120,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":false,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":120,"sortable":true},
{"name":"REGION","index":"REGION","width":90,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":90,"sortable":true},
{"name":"COUNTRY","index":"COUNTRY","width":90,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":90,"sortable":true},
{"name":"VENDORS","index":"VENDORS","width":90,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":false,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":90,"sortable":true},
{"name":"ENT_QUEUE_LOCK_BY","index":"ENT_QUEUE_LOCK_BY","hidden":false,"width":90,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"widthOrg":90,"sortable":true},
{"name":"ENT_QUEUE_LOCK_DATE","index":"ENT_QUEUE_LOCK_DATE","hidden":false,"width":90,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"widthOrg":90,"sortable":true}]`

I need to get this:

`[{name:'all',index:'all', width:40,align:"left",resizable:false,sortable:false,editable:true},{"name":"HTML_DEVICE_CNT","index":"HTML_DEVICE_CNT","width":35,"align":"center","editable":true,"sortable":false,"resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":35},
{"name":"edit","index":"edit","width":20,"align":"center","editable":true,"sortable":false,"resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":20},
{"name":"SPONSOR_CLASSIFICATION","index":"SPONSOR_CLASSIFICATION","width":35,"align":"center","editable":true,"sortable":false,"resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":35},
{"name":"ENT_EXCEPTION_QUEUE","index":"ENT_EXCEPTION_QUEUE","width":60,"align":"center","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":60,"sortable":true},
{"name":"QIB","index":"QIB","width":30,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":30,"sortable":true},
{"name":"LAST_NAME","index":"LAST_NAME","width":120,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":120,"sortable":true},
{"name":"FIRST_NAME","index":"FIRST_NAME","width":120,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":120,"sortable":true},
{"name":"INSTITUTION_TYPE","index":"INSTITUTION_TYPE","width":120,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":120,"sortable":true},
{"name":"INSTITUTION_NAME","index":"INSTITUTION_NAME","width":190,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":190,"sortable":true},
{"name":"EXEMPTION","index":"EXEMPTION","width":70,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":70,"sortable":true},
{"name":"GRAND_PARENT","index":"GRAND_PARENT","width":80,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":80,"sortable":true},
{"name":"GFCID","index":"GFCID","width":80,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":80,"sortable":true},
{"name":"CONTACTID","index":"CONTACTID","width":80,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":80,"sortable":true},
{"name":"CREATED_DATE","index":"CREATED_DATE","width":90,"align":"left","resizable":false,"formatter":"date","formatoptions":{"srcformat":"Y-m-d","newformat":"m-d-Y"},"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":90,"sortable":true},
{"name":"TIERS","index":"TIERS","width":200,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":200,"sortable":true},
{"name":"EMAIL_ADDRESS","index":"EMAIL_ADDRESS","width":120,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":false,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":120,"sortable":true},
{"name":"ALTERNATE_EMAIL_ADDRESS","index":"ALTERNATE_EMAIL_ADDRESS","width":120,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":false,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":120,"sortable":true},
{"name":"REGION","index":"REGION","width":90,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":90,"sortable":true},
{"name":"COUNTRY","index":"COUNTRY","width":90,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":90,"sortable":true},
{"name":"VENDORS","index":"VENDORS","width":90,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":false,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":90,"sortable":true},
{"name":"ENT_QUEUE_LOCK_BY","index":"ENT_QUEUE_LOCK_BY","hidden":false,"width":90,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"widthOrg":90,"sortable":true},
{"name":"ENT_QUEUE_LOCK_DATE","index":"ENT_QUEUE_LOCK_DATE","hidden":false,"width":90,"align":"left","resizable":false,"title":true,"widthOrg":90,"sortable":true}]`.

The result has to be in the form of a JSON array and not a string as it is a colModel for a jqGrid.

Comment: `I have json array:` that's not an array, for starters

Comment: Can you trim down your question? We don't need that much sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array, for example `data[0].PREFERENCESMODEL`, and you want to insert another item `preferencecolModel` at the beginning of the array then you can use `unshift` method:

```js
data[0].PREFERENCESMODEL.unshift(preferencecolModel);
```

I don't see any `label` properties in the `colModel` items. Thus you probably have *another array* with `colNames` items, for example `data[0].PREFERENCESCOLUMNNAMES`. jqGrid require that both arrays `colModel` and `colNames` have the same length. Thus you have to insert one item in `colNames` too. For example, an empty string, which will be displayed in the column header of the inserted column

```js
data[0].PREFERENCESCOLUMNNAMES.unshift("");
```